# Summing up values and store to dictionary via standard iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following data:

```
foo a 199
foo b 200
foo c 300
foo a 103
foo b 400
foo c 120
bar a 100
bar b 100
bar c 100
```

What I want to get is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{foo:{a:302,   # 199 + 103
      b:600,   # 200 + 400
      c:420,}, # 300 + 120
 bar:{a:100,
      b:100,
      c:100}}
```

I'm stuck with this code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

outerdict = defaultdict(dict)
with open('myinputabove.txt','r') as tsvfile:
    tabheader = csv.reader(tsvfile,delimeter=" ")
    for row in tabheader:
        val1 = row[0]
        val2 = row[1]
        val3 = row[2]
        outerdict[val1][val2] += val3
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path. A couple of modifications to your code fixes the problem.

- When you parse with the `csv` module, each element is a string. So you
  have to convert `val3` to int before you add it.
- You have to handle the `KeyError`s that may arise while adding an element to the innter dict.

The following code works:

```
outerdict = defaultdict(dict)
with open('file.txt','r') as tsvfile:
    tabheader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in tabheader:
        val1 = row[0]
        val2 = row[1]
        val3 = row[2]
        try:
            outerdict[val1][val2] += int(val3)
        except KeyError:
            outerdict[val1][val2] = int(val3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`outerdict[val1]` will be a `dict`, even if `val1 in outerdict` is false, because `outerdict` is a `defaultdict`. But `outerdict[val1][val2]` might result in a key error if `val2 in outerdict[val1]` is false, because `outerdict[val1]` is just a `dict`, not a `defaultdict`.

Try `outerdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))`.

Alternatively, if you're okay with a result that looks like this instead:

```
{
    ('foo', 'a'): 302,
    ('foo', 'b'): 600,
    ('foo', 'c'): 420,
    ('bar', 'a'): 100,
    ('bar', 'b'): 100,
    ('bar', 'c'): 100
}
```

You can use `outerdict = defaultdict(int)` and `outerdict[val1,val2] += val3`.